# How Do I List Data From One Column If Data From Two Other Columns Match

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas, array-formulas

[Click Here to View the Example Data Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZccnG.png)

Here is my issue...

I understand this may sound confusing and I'm not sure how to properly articulate so let me describe what I'm looking for based upon the image associated with the link above...

Right now in column C I have the unique values of column B listed using =unique(B:B). I use the unique formula because it is pulling data from a database that is updating daily so I want the formula to update automatically. Every time one of the unique values from column C shows up in column B I would like to list the corresponding values in column A next to the unique value in column C.

> For example let's look at column C, row 2. The value is 4. Every time
>   the value 4 shows up in column B I would like the value of column A in
>   the corresponding row to list itself next to the unique value of
>   column C. So in this example you can see that the values a,b,v showed
>   up in column A when column C had a value of 4. And the values a,b,v
>   are listed to the right of Column C Row 2.

Hopefully this is a clear enough description of what I'm looking for. I can't seem to figure out a proper formula to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Place this formula in D1 and copy it down.

```
=transpose(unique((filter($A$1:$A$10,$B$1:$B$10=$C1))))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much

Comment: @user3573964 You are welcome. If this works for you could you please accept the answer. Thank you.